# Using R::split() to separate data into groups according to names

Tags: r, split, fasta

Consider the following structure called `x` whose output is a vector in R:

```
> x
    A
    A
    A
    B
    B
    C
```

I'd like to use `split` to split `x` into 3 groups A, B, and C where A has 3 elements, B has 2, and C has 1.

What should the grouping factor argument, `f`,  be in `split()`?

The above is a trivial example. My structure is much larger.

My real example consists of FASTA headers where multiple DNA sequences correspond to the same species and I need to split according to species. However, the species name occurs in the header like this:

```
">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P"
```

Here the species is *Agabus adpressus*.

As I am unsure of the most appropriate output at this stage, it could look like

```
$`Agabus adpressus`
Seq1
Seq2
Seq3
```

Comment: Is your real data a vector of strings or is it a dataframe?

Comment: also, what is your expected output? A list of dataframes split by species?

Comment: It will help if you edit the question to include a small dataset which is representative of your **real data**, and an example of the desired output.

Comment: @AndS. Yes, `x` is a vector, and so is the structure for my real data

Comment: `split(x,x)` should give you what you want

Comment: @AndS. `split()` returns a list of vectors by default, according to the help documentation. I think it should be fairly easy to convert to a different format if needed down the line (I am not sure at this point of the best output).

Comment: I'm assuming your real data does not have all the same values per species, correct?

Comment: @AndS. Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that your real data is not uniform in that every string for the same species is exactly the same. In that case, you need to pull the species out of the string to split on:

```r
vals <- c(">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P",
                 ">CZLFG631-11|MZ730009|Agabus|adpressus|BSF8945|AOL-5N",
                 ">XOLGG558-12|MK630011|Agabus|adpressus|JLD6018|CVI-1P",
                 ">YPLFG578-81|JF830122|Agabus|ajax|XCV0091|CMM-1N",
                 ">CLVFG679-13|KA301202|Agabus|ajax|FFP1111|AND-5Z")


split(vals, sub("(?:(.*)\\|){2}(\\w+)\\|(\\w+)\\|.*?$", "\\1-\\2", vals))
#> $`Agabus-adpressus`
#> [1] ">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P"
#> [2] ">CZLFG631-11|MZ730009|Agabus|adpressus|BSF8945|AOL-5N"
#> [3] ">XOLGG558-12|MK630011|Agabus|adpressus|JLD6018|CVI-1P"
#> 
#> $`Agabus-ajax`
#> [1] ">YPLFG578-81|JF830122|Agabus|ajax|XCV0091|CMM-1N"
#> [2] ">CLVFG679-13|KA301202|Agabus|ajax|FFP1111|AND-5Z"
```

Comment: This looks like it'll do the trick but the atomic vector syntax `$...` might complicate things down the road in my pipeline. Is there a ay to have species names as, say, `Agabus adpressus` instead of  `Agabus-adpressus`?

Comment: there is not actually a `$` there. That is just how the list prints. You can access the list using `[[`  with no `$`

Comment: you can change the `Agabus-adpressus` to `Agabus adpressus` by changing `"\\1-\\2"` to `"\\1 \\2"`. The 1 and 2 refer to the two string capture groups and the dash is just how I separated the groups. You can separate any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
read.table(text = vals, sep='|')|>
   split(~paste(V3,V4))|>
   map(~invoke(str_c, .x, sep='|'))

$`Agabus adpressus`
[1] ">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P"
[2] ">CZLFG631-11|MZ730009|Agabus|adpressus|BSF8945|AOL-5N"
[3] ">XOLGG558-12|MK630011|Agabus|adpressus|JLD6018|CVI-1P"

$`Agabus ajax`
[1] ">YPLFG578-81|JF830122|Agabus|ajax|XCV0091|CMM-1N"
[2] ">CLVFG679-13|KA301202|Agabus|ajax|FFP1111|AND-5Z"
```

Although you could split, I would recommend using `group_by` which works similarly and its easier to use